# Multi-dimension dynamic rnn with tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

In tensorflow's dynamic_rnn function, I was surprised by the output shape and I was hoping someone could help improve my understanding of the RNN cells.

For example, if the input is defined as:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [110, seq_size, input_dim])
```

where seq_size = 5 and input_dim = 2 (ie. two time series) and 110 is the batch size; and the cell is defined as,

```
cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(hidden_dim)
```

where hidden_dim = 6

When I create a dynamic_rnn

```
outputs, states = rnn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

and check the size of output it is [110 5 6]. These dimensions are batch size by seq_size by hidden_dim.

Questions:

1: These dimensions imply there are 6 hidden nodes per time step in the time series for a total of 30 hidden nodes (5 x 6) rather than 6 hidden nodes total. Is this the correct interpretation?

2: Since my input dimension is 5 x 2 (5 steps in each sequence and 2 sequences) how is tensorflow connecting the inputs to the hidden nodes at each time step? Is the tensorflow assuming a fully connected graph with 2 inputs, 12 weights, and 6 biases before each hidden cell? Or something else?

Comment: Question 1: there are 5 hidden nodes per sequence, each hidden node corresponding to one input/word.
Question 2: each input is a vector in a 2 dimensional space (for your example).

Comment: Not understanding the answer to number 1. I had originally thought the same, that there would be one hidden node corresponding to each word/input, but the dimensions of output above seem to indicate that's not the case.  In the above example, for each batch element there is [1 5 6], so 30 outputs. Also, the number of hidden nodes is an independent variable for the Cell, as shown in examples like https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.ipynb.

Comment: I think [1 5 6] means there are 5 outputs, and each output is a 6 dimensional vector. You provided [1 5 2], meaning 5 inputs, and each input is a 2 dimensional vector.

Comment: I see. Looking at the equation, I think I see what you are saying. H(t) = f(Winx(t)+WhH(t-1)). I had originally thought that x was 5 by 2, and when I specify the number of hidden cells, I am specifying the row space of W which would be 6 by 5, which would result in 6 by 2 output, however, it seems you are saying x is 2 by 5, and Win is 6 by 2, which is resulting in 6 by 5 output.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a sequence as a sentence and an input as a word. The sequence length is the number of words in the sentence, which is also the number of hidden nodes in LSTM; each input/word is corresponding to one hidden node, which maps the input to one output. This is why the number of output is seq_size (5).

A word is a vector, that is positioned in a multi-dimensional space, whose number of dimensions is input_dim. In LSTM, a word is mapped from this input space to a higher dimensional space whose number of dimensions is hidden_dim. This is why the size of each output is hidden_dim (6).

I believe epoch is an irrelevant concept for this discussion. Please see  [The meaning of batch_size in ptb_word_lm (LSTM model of tensorflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41338553/the-meaning-of-batch-size-in-ptb-word-lm-lstm-model-of-tensorflow/41339126#41339126)

Comment: Updated the questions to be more clear. I suppose my specific question lies in in this phrase "a word is mapped from this input space to a higher dimensional space". How is mapping done? If my word were in Real N-D space, how is each dimension mapped to the higher dimensional space (hidden space).

Comment: The dimension is expanded by multiplying input_vector with a weight_matrix where weight_matrix is of size input_dim x output_dim.

Comment: Also, given the link, I realized I am using epoch as an overloaded term when looking at tensorflow. Epoch in the above question is used as a specific row of inputs in multiple time series (an instance in time, ie. an instance in the seq_size) rather than traditional tensorflow flow use of passes over batches.

Comment: I don't think epoch could be overloaded in that way, which would be confusing for everyone. It has its own specific meaning in neural network training.

Comment: Replaced use of epoch to be more in line with neural networks.